# How to conditionally return a field if it is not empty using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 2 mongoose models, one for books and one for authors. The author is embedded in the book document

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        minLength: 3,
        maxlength: 80,
        required: true
    },
```

and to query the books I am doing this

```js
    async getBook(pid) {
        let book = await Book.findOne({
            _id: pid
        })
        .populate('user', 'name username')
        ;

        if (!book) {
            return false;
        }
        return book;
    }
```

This works as expected returning name and username of the author.

However, what I would like to do is to return the name if username is empty, or only return the username if username is not empty. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 2):

The desired behaviour is achievable through `$ifNull` when wrangling the lookup subpipeline.

```js
db.Book.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: {
        $in: [
          "b1",
          "b2",
          "b3"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "User",
      "let": {
        user: "$user"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$user",
                "$_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            name: {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$username",
                "$name"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$user"
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Fe70wgZI9n2) for your reference.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how to apply this to my code.

Comment: @user3174311 you can use [Aggregate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) in Mongoose to execute native MongoDB aggregation.